# How to sum a column in GridView then display to label in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been looking for the solution for this problem but most of them does not fix it or I don't understand. This is my attempt trying to sum up the whole single column:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <GridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
        }
        Label_Grand.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

The error shows up at `sum += Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);` the word Value.

> 'TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Rob, what error are you getting? That code looks okay to me.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler I have included the error im getting. sorry for not clarifying that

Comment: hi @NoSaidTheCompiler, can u help me with this error please

Comment: Sure, I will try. Hang on... did the answer below from haldo work?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler apparently another error shows up. i thought it would have solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Text` instead.  Also, based on your comments you have `Money` set in the database which should map to `decimal` in C#.

```
decimal sum = 0.0m;
for (int i = 0; i <GridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    sum += Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
}
```

GridViewRow [Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells?view=netframework-4.8) do not have a Value property.

Comment: This error pops up. System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' sorry

Comment: Well, there's at least one value that is not an int then.  Figure out what values are in that column. Maybe log to the debug console instead of converting to int. Could it be an index issue, `Cells[3]` maybe?  Another option is to use `int.TryParse` @RobWebs

Comment: Are they `double` or `decimal` values? Or definitely `int`s? @RobWebs

Comment: i have five column in the gridview and the subtotal is the last coulmn. and I put Money as the Data type in the database.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  You should use `Convert.ToDecimal` and change the type to `decimal sum` @Rob